# How to make the nested items of array to object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a nested array like this:

```
var arr = [
            ['Simcard', 'one'],
            ['Charge', 'two'],
          ];
```

I want to make it like this:

```
[
   {"Simcard": "one"},
   {"Charge": "two"},
]
```

How can I do that?

---

Here is what I've tried but not exactly the expected result:

```
let res = Object.keys(x).map((key) => {key: x[key]});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a builtin [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) that turns a two-element array into an object.

```js
var arr = [
            ['Simcard', 'one'],
            ['Charge', 'two'],
          ];

var desired = [
   {"Simcard": "one"},
   {"Charge": "two"},
]

var answer = arr.map(entry => Object.fromEntries([entry]));

console.log(answer)
```

Comment: this isn't actually the same output the OP asks for

Comment: good point, will fix

Comment: OK, now it matches :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a oneliner, but you could try the following

```
let res = []
arr.forEach(element => res[element[0]] = element[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let res = arr.map(item => ({[item[0]]: item[1]}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#map` as follows. I think you biggest challenge was having the key in a variable: so that the word `key` does not become the key but it's value we use `[key]` instead.

```js
const arr = [ ['Simcard', 'one'], ['Charge', 'two'] ],

      res = arr.map(([key,value]) => ({[key]: value}));
      
console.log( res );
```